# How to switch Qt5 Controls QML styles in realtime

Tags: c++, qt, qml

So my objective is to set up themes for an application that I have made. I would like to be able to check a menu option that will change the theme of the application as soon as I press it; and change the theme back to the native one on pressing the button. I understand how to style the Qt Quick Controls but I am having trouble with the loading and unloading of these themes. Currently my application comes with the native-like theme that Qt Controls comes with. I am able to load custom styles but I am unable to swap them the custom styles and the native theme. How would I go about creating this feature?

For example I am trying to swap the theme of a TableView. I first tried setting a property of TableViewStyle to be styleData.value This produced the desired effect of keeping the native-like theme, but now how would I go about assigning the Rectangle QmlObject to a property value? The interpreter complains about how I cannot assign a Object to a property.

```
TableViewStyle {
    property string color: styleData.value
    headerDelete: color                      // This does not work. Because 
                                             // styleData.value in undefined

    //property string color: rect            // Currently doing this does not
    //Rectangle {id: rect; color: "red"}     // have any effect on the value of
    //headerDelegate: color                  // the headerDelegate. Putting the
                                             // Rectangle in a Component produces
                                             // The same value too.

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a way to go back to the default style without having to load the element first with the default style and save it but this works for a `Button` switching between two custom styles and the default `ButtonStyle`

```
// Property used to save the default ButtonStyle
property var defaultStyle: undefined
// Property used to know the current style
property string currentStyle: "blue"

Button {
  id: myBtn
    text: qsTr("Hello World")
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    onClicked: {
      if(currentStyle == "blue") {
        style = myButtonStyleRed;
        currentStyle = "red";
      } else if(currentStyle == "red") {
        style = defaultStyle;
        currentStyle = "default";
      } else {
        style = myButtonStyleBlue;
        currentStyle = "blue";
      }
    }

    // Save the default Button style on load before switching to the blue one
    Component.onCompleted: {
      defaultStyle = myBtn.style;
      myBtn.style = myButtonStyleBlue;
    }
}

Component {
  id: myButtonStyleBlue
  ButtonStyle {
    label: Text {
      color: "blue"
      text: control.text
    }
  }
}

Component {
  id: myButtonStyleRed
  ButtonStyle {
    label: Text {
      color: "red"
      text: control.text
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey this works just as I needed it too. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Great! Not sure if there is a cleaner/better way to do this

Comment: I'll play around with it and send you an update if I find a better way.